# Join columns in a single Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've DataFrame with 4 columns and want to merge the first 3 columns in a new DataFrame.

The data is identical, the order is irrelevant and any duplicates must remain.

```
import pandas as pd 
   
data = [['tom', 'nick', 'john', 10], ['bob', 'jane', 'nick', 15]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4'])
```

Desired DataFrame

```
+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|
+-----+-----+
|tom  |10   |
|nick |10   |
|john |10   |
|bob  |15   |
|jane |15   |
|nick |15   |
+-----+-----+
```

How do I get this done?

Comment: [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) them:  `df.melt(df.columns[3:])` ? or stack: `df.set_index(list(df.columns[3:])).stack().reset_index(0)`

Comment: @anky Many thanks. What if i want to merge only column 1 en 3. It tried `df.set_index(list(df.columns[1,3])).stack().reset_index(0)` but that failed.

Comment: Np :) if you can clarify exactly what would you have as an input, we can try for an answer, right now based on your comment you can try `df.set_index(list(df.columns ^ df.columns[np.r_[1,3]])).stack().reset_index()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of merging the first three columns with the help of `numpy`:

```
a = df.values
pd.DataFrame({'col_a': np.ravel(a[:, :3]), 'col_b': np.repeat(a[:, 3], 3)})
```

---

```
  col_a col_b
0   tom    10
1  nick    10
2  john    10
3   bob    15
4  jane    15
5  nick    15
```

Comment: Many thanks. What if i want to merge only column 1 en 3

Comment: @JohnDoe I guess you can do `pd.DataFrame({'Col_a': np.ravel(a[:, [0, 2]]), 'Col_b': np.repeat(a[:, 3], 2)})`